# Variance convergence: proof verification

Tags: limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{X_{n,1}:1,\dotsc,n; n\geq 1\}$ be an array of random variables. 
Assume that $$\lvert Var(X_{n,i})-\sigma^2 \rvert\to 0, \text{ as } n\to\infty,$$
uniformly in $i$. Show that
$$\frac{1}{r_n}\sum_{i=1}^{r_n}Var(X_{n,i})\to\sigma^2,$$
where $r_n$ is a divergent sequence of real numbers.

It seems to be right to me, but I'm struggled to show this limit since the variance and $r_n$ depend on $n$. If it was a finite sum, then the result easily follows. Can you help me with this?

**My attempt**
\begin{align}
\bigg\lvert \frac{1}{r_n}\sum_{i=1}^{r_n}Var(X_{n,i})-\sigma^2 \bigg\rvert
&=\bigg\lvert \frac{1}{r_n}\sum_{i=1}^{r_n}(Var(X_{n,i})-\sigma^2) \bigg\rvert
\leq  \frac{1}{r_n}\sum_{i=1}^{r_n}\lvert Var(X_{n,i})-\sigma^2\rvert\\
&\leq \sup_i \lvert Var(X_{n,i})-\sigma^2\rvert\leq \delta
\end{align}
for $\delta>0$, and $n$ sufficiently large.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By "divergent" do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty} r_n = +\infty$?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes!!